# Change the image layer on revolution slider

Tags: wordpress

I have a slider template on rev slider from a template I bought.

I am trying to change the source of an image in the layer, but can't find the option or documentation anywhere online. Only how to change a background image, this isn't a background image, it is an image layer.

If I try adding a new image, whenever I move, the image gets locked to the side or vanishes completely when trying to edit the slide.

Thus, I want to just replace the source of the current image, so I can keep the image in the same place etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the source of an image layer. You **can** do that with a background image (change the source of it) but not with the image layer.

The easiest thing your you to do would be to add a new image layer and then play with it until you get the right size or until it doesn't snap to the side. Alternatively you can just recreate the whole slide and first enter just image layers. You can always [reposition layers](https://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/layer-styles-positioning/) .

**Update 01/10/18:**

Well, I found out a solution, to anyone who will be looking how to do this. While editing a slide, you will have two buttons right above the slide editor, named "Object Library" and "Add Layer". Next to it click on the "hamburger" icon and find the layer for which you want to change the image source - once you find it, click the pen icon next to it and choose your new image. [View this tutorial](https://www.themepunch.com/faq/change-image-template/) and check step 4.

Answer (score 2):

Select layer image or object by left-click, or right-click and choose the layer you need.

Right above there is a menu with Style, Animation, Loop, Visibility... etc.

Near "Style" button there is an arrow down, click it.

Advanced Style menu opens, click "Background".

Second left is "Backround Image" option (image icon) choose an image source (Media Library or Object Library) and upload it.

There are plenty of useful attributes in this menu also, check it.

Voila!

Answer (score 2):

to change the desired layer photo
**Double-click** the layer in the slide area and select the desired image from the library.
Good luck